# Basic Perceptron or Single layer Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a doubt regarding basic perceptron. Can basic perceptron classify points in R^2 or R^3? Can someone justify it? Note: R^n refers to n-dimensional Euclidean Space.

Comment: I think you should try asking this question in https://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

A single layer perceptron can only draw a line (y = ax + b), therefore It would not be able to understand a parabola or other type of curve in order to predict.